# Where Does Prisma save records in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, nestjs, prisma

I started using prisma and noticed that while accessing the database directly I can not see the records that I put earlier into the table using prisma ORM. psql simply tells me that relation does not exists

```
   nest=# select * from Test;
    ERROR:  relation "test" does not exist
    LINE 1: select * from Test;
```

here are the tables and sequences

```
nest=# \d
                 List of relations
 Schema |        Name        |   Type   |  Owner
--------+--------------------+----------+----------
 public | Test               | table    | postgres
 public | Test_id_seq        | sequence | postgres
 public | User               | table    | postgres
 public | User_id_seq        | sequence | postgres
 public | _prisma_migrations | table    | postgres
(5 rows)
```

But while using prisma studio all of my records are accessible and I don't understand how it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the query as `SELECT * FROM "Test"`. The quotes are very important here, because Postgres by default will make anything that's not quoted lowercase. Because your table is named `Test`, you will have to always have the table written as `"Test"` in your queries